# Code coverage in codecov.io

Tags: node.js, code-coverage, travis-ci, package.json

I have setup devdependies in my package.json file for codegov.io and made a script for it in the same file. I am using Istanbul for the code coverage itself.
Furthermore I have updated my Travis.yml for it also. Travis is running fine and the build and test go through. 
I have a user account at Codecov but I don't seem to see any coverage reports in Codecov for my git repo.

```
{
  "name": "canis-familiaris",
  "version": "0.0.0-semantically-released",
  "description": "Dog breeds",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "commit": "git-cz",
    "check-coverage": "istanbul check-coverage --statements 100 --branches 100 --functions 100 --lines 100",
    "report-coverage": "cat ./coverage/lcov.info | codecov",
    "test": "mocha src/index.test.js -w",
    "test-single": "istanbul cover -x *.test.js _mocha -- -R spec src/index.test.js",
    "semantic-release": "semantic-release pre && npm publish && semantic-release post"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/mig-25/Canis-familiaris.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Dogs",
    "Breed"
  ],
  "author": "Sohail Hasware <saab.viggen@live.se>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/mig-25/Canis-familiaris/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/mig-25/Canis-familiaris#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "unique-random-array": "1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "codecov.io": "0.1.6",
    "commitizen": "2.8.6",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "1.2.0",
    "ghooks": "1.3.2",
    "istanbul": "0.4.5",
    "mocha": "3.0.2",
    "semantic-release": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "czConfig": {
    "path": "node_modules/cz-conventional-changelog"
  },
  "config": {
    "ghooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run test-single && npm run check-coverage"
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my Travis:

```
sudo: false
language: node_js
cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules
notifications:
  email: false
node_js:
  - 'iojs'
before_install:
  - npm i -g npm@^2.0.0
before_script:
  - npm prune
script:
  - npm run test-single
  - npm run check-coverage
after_success:
  - npm report-coverage
  - npm run semantic-release
branches:
  except:
    - /^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Breds,
Sohail

Comment: Try ~npm report-coverage~ `npm run report-coverage` Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for asking. I believe there is a syntax issue in your `.travis.yml` preventing coverage from executing.

`- npm report-coverage
+ npm run report-coverage`

Codecov support team is happy to help out. Please contact us at  https://codecov.io/support